# Uncaught Error: Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found

Tags: php, simplexml, php-7

SimpleXMLElement doesn't work!

Check php -v:

```
PHP 7.4.8 (cli) (built: Jul 13 2020 16:45:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

php -m:

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
SimpleXML
..
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
...
```

I used PHP 7.2, install php-xml, php-simplexml and etc.

log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found in /var/www/html/inc/functions.php:828
```

php:

```
 $myCurl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array($body))
  ));
  $response = curl_exec($myCurl);
  curl_close($myCurl);
  
$robo_response = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

Comment: try the following: `$robo_response = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);`

Comment: I trying. I have error, too.

Comment: You've shared the command-line configuration but you run code form `/var/www/html`, what suggests a web server. Could you please confirm what your environment is?

Comment: i am also facing the same problem. 
its working fine on local (win) Not working on live server (Azure ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Ubuntu enabled PHP7.0. Need PHP 7.4

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Thx for help everybody.